# How can I intercept the HTTP request of a PHP Soap Client?

Tags: php, http, soap, document-body

I have implemented a SoapClient in PHP and I need to debug calls made to the Soap server. I would like to intercept the HTTP calls when I run my PHP code in order to retrieve the body content.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this? I am under Linux.

Comment: Extend the [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) class and redefine the method [`__doRequest()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php). This is where the HTTP request is sent to the server. If you are happy with the default implementation, all you have to do is to log the values it receives as arguments, call the parent implementation, log the value it returns and also return it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend the [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) class and redefine the method [`__doRequest()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php). This is where the HTTP request is sent to the server. If you are happy with the default implementation, all you have to do is to log the values it receives as arguments, call the parent implementation, log the value it returns and also return it. Use the new class instead of `SoapClient` whenever you need to log the communication between the SOAP client and server.

Something along these lines:

```
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    public string __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        // Log the request here
        echo('$action='.$action."\n");
        echo('$request=[[['.$request."]]]\n");

        // Let the parent class do the job
        $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);

        // Log the response received from the server
        echo('$response=[[['.$response."]]]\n");

        // Return the response to be parsed
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Use the log method of your choice instead of `echo()` in the code above.

Comment: Ok, trying this tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: If the php script is making a request to another IP, then you could also use a packet capture utility like Wireshark to snoop on the transfer.  This won't require you to touch your code.

Comment: @Adrien your suggestion is correct but in certain conditions it is impossible to apply. Running a sniffer on the computer requires shell access and root permissions on the computer where you want to run it (usually on the web server). These conditions are met when you own the server but they are impossible to get when the code is hosted. Changing the code is easy and always works.

Comment: In recent PHP versions `__doRequest` does not return the response anymore. Hence, you need to first invoke the parent and then do `parent::__getLastResponse();`. I have a sample here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53355614/131929